# Make automatic deployment in Visual Studio

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I want to create automatic deployment system in my Visual Studio 2013 without TFS.
The basic algorithm that I want to implement:

1. Clean Solution.
2. Build Solution.
3. Copy Files To Server.
4. Run All Tests.
5. If (TestFailed)
   5.1. Then Run-Rollback-Script.
   5.2. Else Run-Success-Script.

And if it possible, I want it to run only in specific solution condition (Release).

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What kind of tests do you want to run? Unit tests, UI tests, load tests?

Comment: In the solution I have unit tests project. So I want to run this project.

Comment: Have you looked at post build events?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to run test from there and use the results as conditions.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder Do you have any idea how to do it?